# Can anybody tell me how to test ftp server in Ubuntu machine?

Tags: ftp

I tried with several ways which is given like telnet to test whether my ftp server working properly or not:

1. ```
   rama@rama-desktop:~$ telnet 192.164.0.102 21
   Trying 192.168.0.102...
   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
   rama@rama-desktop:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1 21
   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
   ```
2. ```
   ftp ramaftp@127.0.0.1
   ftp: ramaftp@127.0.0.1: No address associated with hostname
   ```

   In the above, `ramaftp` is the username that I have created earlier.

I am a novice in Ubuntu. Please help me to reset the ftp username and password for my machine.

I have tried:

1. `sudo mkdir /srv/ftp`
2. `sudo usermod -d /srv/ftp ftp`
3. `sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart`
4. Modified conf file:

   ```
   local_enable=YES
   write_enable=YES
   ```
5. restarted server with `service vsftpd restart`:

   ```
   stop: Unknown instance: 
   start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.72" (uid=1000 pid=3629 comm="start vsftpd ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
   ```

This is the error that I got,
Thanks

Comment: Which ftp server are you using?

Comment: It looks like that there is no server running (`Connection refused`) or, less probably, if it is running it's not listening for connections on the right interfaces. Could you tell us something more about your setup? The FTP server software you are using and the way you have installed/configured it are two essential information.

Comment: By the way, the `ftp(1)` program does not accept the user name as an argument; you have first to connect and then use the `user` command. Check `man ftp` for more information.

Comment: vsftp, which is I came to know the best ftp from internet

Comment: let me know the probable reasons to refuse the connection

Comment: Check the output of `status vsftpd` and try `start vsftpd`. If it doesn't resolve the issue, please post the contents of your `/etc/vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: OUT PUT IS LIKE THIS :status vsftpd
vsftpd stop/waiting AND FOR
start vsftpd
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.70" (uid=1000 pid=3522 comm="start vsftpd ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Comment: Please go through my edited question

Comment: @Chella the error you got at the end is because you aren't root. try it with sudo. `sudo start vsftpd` or `sudo service vsftpd start`

Comment: @Chella, this may help [a scenario which depict vsftpd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445296/a-scenario-which-depict-vsftpd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download Filezilla http://filezilla-project.org/download.php
2. extract the downloaded package
3. open bin folder --> filezilla

Filezilla configuration to access an Ubuntu machine 
open site manager --> new site

host: 
Protocol: SFTP
login type : normal

Answer (score 3):

`ftp 127.0.0.1`

OR

`ftp localhost`

The [FTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html) server will ask you for a username and a password.. plain simple! :)

Comment: good answer but getting the same error
ftp 127.0.0.1
ftp: connect: Connection refused
ftp>

Comment: check if your ftp is running or firewall.

Comment: Did you checked out the settings file that actually ALLOWS connections from the localhost?, sometimes all this options are in "OFF" mode so that you have to actually turn it on.

Also, as maniat1k sugested there also can be some rule at the local firewall that is actually blocking the connection from the localhost. To make sure the ftp server is running you can do this (i will use vsftpd as an example): sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd stop and the do a sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd start.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
wget -O /dev/null -q  ftp://192.168.1.55
```

Returns `0` if the server is up, otherwise returns positive/negaive value.

Expanation:

`wget` tries to reach the url, in this case an `ftp` server. The `-O` option redirects the output, if any, to `/dev/null` so it is not written to a file not to `stdout`. The `-q` option suppresses any additional output (like progress bar). The only remaining thing is the return value, which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your ftp programme and enter the following details:

- Protocol: SFTP
- Host: **127.0.0.1**
- Port: **22**
- username: **root**
- Password: ******************
- Path: **/var/www/**

This should give you access to your 'local' server.

[image: Screen Shot]