# a scenario which depict vsftpd

Tags: vsftpd

I downloaded vsftpd, install and config based on this link [How to Set up an FTP Server in Ubuntu Linux](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-an-FTP-Server-in-Ubuntu-Linux) On my Ubuntu 12.04. But the question is how to test that?

I want to learn how to use vsftpd and I am looking for an *easy graphical step by step scenario* to learn that. Like a scenario which include client and server by using *virtual box*?

How to download a file from Ubuntu_2 in Ubuntu_1. Which both are virtual OS in Virtual box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Server side

1. Check service status

   ```
   sudo service vsftpd status
   ```
2. Check its running processes

   ```
   ps ax | grep vsftpd
   ```

   (Command to: list all processes then filter output for vsftpd line)

   or you can use a loop to monitor its processes:

   ```
   while sleep 1 ; do clear ; ps ax | grep vsftpd ; done
   ```

   (Command to: wait 1 second, clear shell screen, list all processes then filter output for vsftpd line, loop again as sleep always return succefully)
3. Check port status related to vsftpd process

   ```
   netstat -lnp | grep vsftpd
   ```

   (Command to: list all listening ports with port number and process id (PID) owning it then filter output for vsftpd line)
4. Monitor server log (`tail` with `-f` to follow log updates and monitor vsftpd)

   ```
   $ tail -f /var/log/vsftpd.log
   Fri Apr 25 18:43:28 2014 [pid 2026] CONNECT: Client "127.0.0.1"
   Fri Apr 25 18:45:01 2014 [pid 2025] [sneetsher] OK LOGIN: Client "127.0.0.1"
   ```

### Client side

(note: I run them from server just to make examples, prefer other host to check firewall settings...)

1. `ftp` command with `-v` verbose option to show all responses from the remote server)

   ```
   $ ftp -v localhost
   Connected to localhost.
   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
   Name (localhost:sneetsher):      
   331 Please specify the password.
   Password:
   230 Login successful.
   Remote system type is UNIX.
   Using binary mode to transfer files.
   ftp>
   ```
2. FileZilla. It has very detailed log, but it sends couple commands depending on settings which not always what you want.

   ```
   Status: Resolving address of localhost
   Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
   Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
   Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
   Command:    USER sneetsher
   Response:   331 Please specify the password.
   Command:    PASS ********
   Response:   230 Login successful.
   Command:    SYST
   Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
   Command:    FEAT
   Response:   211-Features:
   Response:    EPRT
   Response:    EPSV
   Response:    MDTM
   Response:    PASV
   Response:    REST STREAM
   Response:    SIZE
   Response:    TVFS
   Response:    UTF8
   Response:   211 End
   Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
   Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
   Status: Connected
   Status: Retrieving directory listing...
   Command:    PWD
   Response:   257 "/home/sneetsher"
   Command:    TYPE I
   Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
   Command:    PASV
   Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,159,231).
   Command:    LIST
   Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
   Response:   226 Directory send OK.
   Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
   Command:    MDTM 0000_12.04~
   Response:   213 20140208184211
   Status: Timezone offsets: Server: 0 seconds. Local: 0 seconds. Difference: 0 seconds.
   Status: Directory listing successful
   ...
   Status: Sending keep-alive command
   Command:    TYPE I
   Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
   ```

### Possible testing workflow

1. Server side: After changing `vsftpd.conf`, restart service (no need to reboot VBox guest)

   ```
   sudo service vsftpd restart
   ```
2. Client side: It's possible to write FTP client scripts (routine tests) using `yafc`. Example to upload a folder:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   yafc <<**
   open ftp://username:password@hostname
   put -f -r folder
   close
   **
   exit 0
   ```

   or using `ftp`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   HOST='ftp.users.qwest.net'
   USER='yourid'
           PASSWD='yourpw'
   FILE='file.txt'

   ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
   quote USER $USER
   quote PASS $PASSWD
   put $FILE
   quit
   END_SCRIPT
   exit 0
   ```

### Server/Client on VirtualBox guests

- Client should be in same NAT Network, Internal Network with server.
- Or if Server has Bridged Adapter, Client could be set with NAT, NAT Network, Bridged Adapter.

**References:**

- [Ubuntu community help wiki: vsftpd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd)
- [`man vsftpd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/vsftpd.8.html), [`man vsftpd.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html)
- [`man service`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/service.8.html), [`man netstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/netstat.8.html)
- [How to use ftp in a shell script](http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can test the VSFTPD server by the following 3 methods:

1. On the ubuntu machine (on which you have installed VSFTPD server), open the terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) and type 'ftp localhost'. Enter the Name and password when prompted.
   On success, You will get into the ftp> prompt.

   Refer: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd
2. Testing the Status of VSFTPD -> Run " netstat -a | grep ftp " on your server.
   If VSFTPD wasn’t running, there would be no output at all.

   Check this link: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=378136&seqNum=6
3. From another ubuntu machine(consider it as FTP client), send or receive some files to/from your FTP server (that is , the machine on which VSFTPD is installed).

   For this, you will have to connect to FTP server from another ubuntu machine.

   Check the list of FTP commands on linux in this link: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/blcmdl1_ftpx.htm

Answer (score 2):

On the ubuntu server, open terminal and type:

```
sudo service vsftpd status
```

if output is like (except for the pid process) :

```
vsftpd start/running, process 6582
```

then the server is running.

From another computer to check if the server is active on the default port (21):

```
telnet ip_server_ftp 21
```

the output will return if the connection has been

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a simple giude in this link http://blog.pluralsight.com/how-to-set-up-safe-ftp-in-linux

and [http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:*Ch15*:_Linux_FTP_Server_Setup#Installing_vsftpd](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch15_:_Linux_FTP_Server_Setup#Installing_vsftpd)

also on virtualBox if from your geust, can not ftp connect to host you should follow here :
[FTP Permissions read but not write](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335040/ftp-permissions-read-but-not-write)

also about .conf file
https://serverfault.com/questions/362619/why-is-the-chroot-local-user-of-vsftpd-insecure

https://serverfault.com/questions/358211/can-i-configure-vsftpd-to-listen-only-to-localhost

https://serverfault.com/questions/34678/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-allow-root-logins

http://xmodulo.com/2014/06/secure-ftp-service-vsftpd-linux.html

Comment: also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=518293